# Change of bases - linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $f:R^2→R^2$ be the linear transformation defined by
$f(x)$=$$(\begin{matrix}3 & -3\\0 & -3 \\\end{matrix})x
$$.

Let
$B = {⟨1,−2⟩,⟨3,−7⟩}, C = {⟨1,−1⟩,⟨−3,2⟩}$,
be two different bases for $R^2$. Find the matrix for $f$ relative to the basis $B$ in the domain and $C$ in the codomain.

I do not understand the wording... what does it mean by ''...to the basis B in the domain and C in the codomain?"" Does it just mean $R^2$ for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(B_1)=(9,6)=-36C_1-15C_2$

$f(B_2)=(30,21)=-123C_1-51C_2 $

So the matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix} -36 & -123 \\ -15 & -51 \end{bmatrix}  $$

Comment: Can you please explain a bit? It is not straightforward to me yet

Comment: In fact, if $B_1=(1,-2)$ we must calculate $$ \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -3 \\ 0 & -3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix} $$ that equls to $(9,6)$. Then we must write $(9,6)$ in the form of $\alpha C_1+\beta C_2$ . Then obtain $\alpha , \beta$. Then we do the same work for $B_2$. After all we obtain a matrix that must write transpose of it.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you!